# Start a program not as a child process

Tags: windows, cmd

I am trying to run a program from cmd, but not as a child of the prompt. I have tried calling the program directly: `program`, but this starts it as a child process. I have tried `start "" program`, but this also starts it as a child process. Is this possible? I don't want the program to close when the prompt is closed.

Edit: This is not a duplicate question - `start` doesn't work in this case. I don't know enough to explain better, but some things to note:

- The program in question doesn't open a new window
- The path to the program contains spaces, so requires inverted commas. However, the inverted commas seem to suggest to `start` that the argument is intended to be the name of the new command window.
- I need to pass switches to the program, which makes things a bit more complicated

Comment: `start` should do it; what program?

Comment: http://www.snakebytestudios.com/projects/apps/cursor-lock/

Comment: If I doubleclick the shortcut the program creates, I get the desired behaviour. However, I want to be able to do this from the command prompt.

Comment: The command I would expect to work is `start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cursor Lock\CursorLock.exe"  /I /M:1` but this launches the program as a child to the prompt.

Comment: If you check out the target of the shortcut you mentioned, you have got the command line to use...

Comment: That's what you'd think. The target of the shortcut is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cursor Lock\CursorLock.exe" /I /M:1, and everything I've tried launches a child process.

Comment: I've tried launching the shortcut from the prompt as well. Again, creates a child process.

Comment: What specifically is the problem of it being a child process? This sounds like an X/Y problem. To be specific, if process A in Windows starts process B, A will be a parent of B and B will be a child of A. You cannot change that. What exactly is it that you want to happen? Or, what is happening that you don't want?

Comment: Additionally, this sounds like a [su] question, unless the problem really is that you're trying to start the second program from within your own program, and not from cmd.

Comment: The issue is that I want the program to persist after the calling command prompt closes. I’m not sure if the question belonged here or on super user, I thought super user was more appropriate but saw similar questions posted here.

Comment: To give a counterexample, consider `start notepad.exe`. The notepad process does not appear as a child process in the task manager, and is not closed when the command prompt exits.

Comment: I think I've worked it out - the particular program I am using defaults to closing when the calling window is closed.